# Windows Command prompt shell for sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) states that there is a command-line shell for sqlite3:

> To start the sqlite3 program, just type "sqlite3" followed by the name the file that holds the SQLite database."

When I try this, in the Windows Command Prompt I get the error message:

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Windows explorer reveals several 'Sqlite3" folders in various places:

```
backends(C:/Python26/Lib/site-packages/django/db)
Lib(C:/Python26)
backends(C:/Django-1.1.1/Django-1.1.1/build/lib/django/db
backends(C:/Django-1.1.1/Django-1.1.1/django/db)
```

How do I access the shell, can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download sqlite3 binary for windows [here](http://sqlite.org/download.html).  Unzip it and put it somewhere in your path.

Comment: sqlite3 came bundled with django-1.1.1. But i cannot find the sqlite3.exe file, so I assume I will have to download it. Thanks.

Comment: `By default, the configuration uses SQLite. If you’re new to databases, or you’re just interested in trying Django, this is the easiest choice. SQLite is included in Python, so you won’t need to install anything else to support your database.` FROM: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 5):

That's the error message you get if you try to run any executable that's not in your current directory or in the path.

To correct the problem, find the SQLite executable (SQLITE3.EXE), and run it from the directory in which it resides, or add SQLITE3.EXE to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to properly set your PATH environment variable to include one of the locations where `sqlite3.exe` resides. Usually SQLite seems to set that environment variable upon install but the list of paths where you found it indicates that it just came as a library for various other applications. Therefore it's not too surprising that the path isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

I have sqlite3 on my machine, and as others have mentioned it must be located within a folder specified by your PATH environment variable. Since I use it a lot, I threw it in windows\system32, which is where I place a lot of utilities like pstools.