# Sqlite3 command not recognized in command prompt (Python2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

im fairly new to sqlite. I ran the 'sqlite3' command in command prompt and the command was not recognized.

I cant find the sqlite3.exe in my python27 installation (so i cant add it to paths)

I also tried adding a path to the sqlite dll which did not work ([Windows Command prompt shell for sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882647/windows-command-prompt-shell-for-sqlite3)).

How can i get this command to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution is to install the 'sqlite-tools' and the 'sqlite-dlls' from the precompiled windows binaries at this link:

http://sqlite.org/download.html