# sqlite3 is not recognized as an external or internal command

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm creating a poll `app` using `django`. When I try to access the `database` using the command `sqlite3 db.sqlite3` as shown in the video I get error:

> 'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I've already manually installed and set the path in environment variables but still its showing error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where are you getting this command from? The documentation? It's been a while since I've looked at the tutorial, but I don't recall any such command. In any case... it sounds like you are typing in a command to the Windows command prompt when it's being expected somewhere else... perhaps a `manage.py` command? E.g. `python manage.py <command>`

Comment: From a youtube tutorial. A channel named PrettyPrinted. I'm using this on cmd. He used it to access the database.

Comment: I just checked out what I think is the same video... It looks like he is actually using an Ubuntu shell. Look at the top-left corner of the Window, it's the Ubuntu logo, not CMD. That could very well be the source of your troubles.

Comment: thank you. I used the same as shown in the video, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the appropriate .exe file from [here](https://sqlite.org/download.html) and put that in you `PATH`.

please refer to this discussion as well [Windows Command prompt shell for sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882647/windows-command-prompt-shell-for-sqlite3?rq=1)

P.S. If at all possible try to use WSL or native linux, as this process becomes much more easier.